# Warning: modules_install: missing 'System.map' file. Skipping depmod

Tags: makefile, linux-kernel, kernel-module, insmod

I am trying to insert a kernel module using `depmod` and `modprobe` utilities in-order to resolve any dependencies. When I build the module it throws "**Warning: modules_install: missing 'System.map' file. Skipping depmod.**"

And later when I try to execute `modprobe` it throws an error saying 
**"modprobe: FATAL: Module i2c_eeprom_client.ko not found in directory /lib/modules/4.19.58-v7+"**

Below is the make file I am using:

```
obj-m += i2c_eeprom_client.o
KDIR = /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
    make -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules_install

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

And below is the output of build:

```
make -C /lib/modules/4.19.58-v7+/build M=/home/pi/work/eeprom modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.58-v7+'
  Building modules, stage 2.   
  MODPOST 1 modules
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.58-v7+'
make -C /lib/modules/4.19.58-v7+/build M=/home/pi/work/eeprom 
modules_install  
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.58-v7+'
  INSTALL /home/pi/work/eeprom/i2c_eeprom_client.ko
  DEPMOD  4.19.58-v7+
Warning: modules_install: missing 'System.map' file. Skipping depmod.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.58-v7+'
```

How can i fix this problem ? Please help

Platform : Raspberry PI 3b+, Raspbian - linux 4.19.58-v7+

Comment: As a side note, doing the install step in the same make target as the build step is a bad idea as you typically need root privileges for the install step, but generally don't need them for the build step.

Comment: Thanks ! 
So how can i fix this problem ? I have tried to do it post build and below is the error i have received.

make: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.58-v7+'

cp: cannot stat './modules.order': No such file or directory

make: *** [Makefile:1253: _modinst_] Error 1

make: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.58-v7+'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can run `depmod` after the `modules_install` step. Also, it is better practice to separate the installation from the building to avoid having to build with root privileges:

```
obj-m += i2c_eeprom_client.o

# Default to running kernel's build directory if KDIR not set externally
KDIR ?= "/lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build"

all:
    $(MAKE) -C "$(KDIR)" M="$(CURDIR)" modules

install:
    $(MAKE) -C "$(KDIR)" M="$(CURDIR)" modules_install
    depmod -A

clean:
    $(MAKE) -C "$(KDIR)" M="$(CURDIR)" clean
```

Invoke as:

```
$ make
$ make install
```

Comment: I have no idea what I just did. Can you give me a little more flavor in terms of context of what just happened when I modified my Makefile like so? I created a brand new libvirt VM using Vagrant's generic/ubuntu2204, and modified this make file in the `kmod` project to include `depmod -A` and it worked. https://github.com/orhun/kmon